# Using original function inside jest mock causes infinite loop

Tags: jestjs, dynamoose

I have a chainable method from  [dynamoose](https://dynamoosejs.com/api/query/) where in testing I would like to add an additional method to the chain.

Essentially, in testing I would like to replace all instances of

```
Model.query(key).otherChainableMethods()
```

with

```
Model.query(key).limit(LIMIT).otherChainableMethods()
```

So I tried:

```
Model.query = jest.fn(key => Model.query(key).limit(LIMIT))
```

but this is clearly causing some sort of infinite loop, because I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

How can use the original implementation of a function inside the mock implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple solution. I can simply store the original method in another variable first.

```
const originalQuery = Profile.query
Profile.query = jest.fn(key => originalQuery(key).limit(LIMIT))
```